# Where To add test command in buildspec.yml file

Tags: continuous-integration, cicd, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, buildspec

I am building a `buildspec` file for my `AWS` code build but I don't know at which phase I need to add `NPM` run test and if the test fails, I expect build to stop.

Here is the `buildspec` I have created:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  parameter-store:
    ECOSYSTEM_CONFIG: "Ecosystem-config"
    ENV: "backend"

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14
    commands:
      - npm install
      - npm install pm2 -g
      - npm install nodemon -g

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo $ENV > .env.dev
      - echo $ECOSYSTEM_CONFIG > ecosystem.config.js

  build:
    commands:
      - pm2 start ecosystem.config.js

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
```

I am expecting my `buildspec` to run and if the test cases fails, the process stops.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where the test command is placed. Instead, you may just need to use `on-failure: ABORT` to instruct the build to stop when the test command fails. For example,

```
  build:
    on-failure: ABORT 
    commands:
      - npm ci
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.phases.on-failure